# Can I configure an app to be always visible across all workspaces?

Tags: window-management, workspace

This appears to happen with a lot of other apps like MonoDevelop, WebStorm, etc.

The right click title bar "Always on visible workspace" is not available on any browser other than the default provided by elementary OS.  In chrome, i have tried the "Right click on title bar, choose 'use system title bar and borders'" but right-clicking on that yields no menu.  I have tried same with Firefox and Opera but cannot get the option to keep the browser on all workspaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to create a keyboard shortcut for this setting which seems to work for any window, including those without title bar menu. It's in **System settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Windows > Toggle on all Workspaces** and it isn't assigned by default.