# Can a window be shown on every desktop?

Tags: release-loki, desktop, window-management, workspace

Just installed eOS (Loki), and I like it so far.  I have one small question that I can't find an answer to online, though:

In Ubuntu, there's an option in a window's title bar context menu to "display on every desktop" so that no matter what workspace I'm on, my Instant Message app is visible (for example).  Is there a similar option for the eOS?

Basically, [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10704/can-i-configure-an-app-to-be-always-visible-across-all-workspaces) (unanswered after 6 months).  Thanks!

Comment: One option: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/16216/15551

Answer (score 1):

Try right-clicking on the windows title bar and selecting "Always on visible workspace"

Comment: Not all applications have the title bar menu available. It seems to be limited to the "native" elementary OS apps.

Comment: @artm I only found a few that don't have this menu available: firefox, chromium, wps-office, which all use custom toolkits and ain't really designed to fit into elementary OS. In most of them you can enable the legacy titlebar, which gives access to the menu (except wps-office >11, which no longer supports it).